# select date field from SQL datasource in appmaker based on drop down value

Tags: google-app-maker

I can not post a comment to another question that exists out there,  so I am asking my own question. I have a drop down,  that consists of "employee name".   I want a date box to auto-populate based on the result of the name selected.   I.E.  John Smith is selected and his DOB is 01/02/1987,  I want this second box to return 01/02/1987.

Things I have tried:

Server side script function,  calling function -- RESULT:  Function not found
Client side script function,  Calling function -- RESULT:  function found,  but can't find references to datasources

On another post,  someone recommended doing options in the dropdown to being @`datasources.Events.items` and then the onChangeEvent being   `widget.root.descendants.DateBox1.value = newValue.Date;`

I have tried this,  however,  I can not stop the "options" at "items".  I am required to proceed through to items.projects.fieldName.  Since I am selecting the fieldName on requirement,   the newValue isn't returning the date based off that field.  It simply says "undefined value"

How should I populate one date box based on the result set of the dropdown box?

Comment: Could you please share a link for the question you are redirecting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187749/select-field-from-sql-datasource-in-appmaker-based-on-drop-down-value

Comment: In some cases you will need to replace your dropdown widget with a new widget. I have had some experiences where parts of a dropdown no longer lets you change bindings to the wanted setting after having set other properties. In that case start with a new widget and set the options binding first.

Comment: Markus,  thank you so much,  this worked.    I still had to keep the old dropdown,   as that is what sets the value into the form,  but the new dropdown created actually allows me to set it up like you stated and have the onChangeEvent to auto populate the 2nd dropdown and the date field.  Thank you so much!